# np.insert command changing the format of zero and one

Tags: python, numpy

I want to insert zero and one at the end of last column of my whole data.

These are actually my labels which I have to convert in one hot vector later. But when I insert them at the end of column and when I print that column it prints as
`[0., 0.,  1.,...]` rather it should be `[0,0,1,....]`.

What should I do to overcome this error? Because with `0.` and `1.` I can't get one hot representation and with these numbers I get error of `unsupported iterator index`. I need the last column as `0` and `1s`.

Can someone please guide me what should I do to fix this error?

```
def set_label(data_all, Labels, hc):
    loc_1=len(data_all[0])
    labels= Labels
    insert_h = np.insert(data_all,loc_1,labels,axis=1)

    label_store =[]
    for i in range(len(labels)):
        hmax = labels[i]
        if hmax < hc:
            label_store.append(0)
        elif hmax > hc:
            label_store.append(1)
    loc_2= len(insert_h[0])

    insert_label =np.insert(insert_h, loc_2, label_store,axis=1)
    return insert_label
```

When I print insert_label of above function I get following result.  zero and one is appearing as `0.0000e+00` and `1.0000e+00`. I want it to be `0` and `1`.

```
[[1.11886399e-01 2.83619339e+00 3.14394233e+001.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00]
[2.29317271e-01 1.87929947e+00 3.14713896e+00 1.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00]
[3.69530173e-02 3.52560100e+00 5.05051823e+00 1.50000000e+00 0.00000000e+00]
[1.56559513e-01 2.10847705e+00 3.88715380e+00 1.50000000e+00 0.00000000e+00] 
[2.44876157e-03 6.02824866e+00 1.02350953e+01 5.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00]
[9.38766706e-03 4.89698950e+00 6.28692713e+00 5.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00]]
```

Here in the input data for calling above function.

```
Labels=[1.  1.  1.5 1.5 5.  5. ]
data_all=[[1.11886399e-01, 2.83619339e+00, 3.14394233e+00]
[2.29317271e-01, 1.87929947e+00, 3.14713896e+00]
[3.69530173e-02, 3.52560100e+00, 5.05051823e+00]
[1.56559513e-01, 2.10847705e+00, 3.88715380e+00]
[2.44876157e-03, 6.02824866e+00, 1.02350953e+01]
[9.38766706e-03, 4.89698950e+00, 6.28692713e+00]]`
```

Function call
    "set_label(data_all,Labels,2)

Comment: Show how you call your function. Provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Why do you have a line line `labels= Labels`?

Comment: I am just storing that in other variable.  I am not getting error because of this label=Labels

Comment: Do you understand what the different outputs mean? In particular, you can't convert dtype with `insert`.

Comment: You're not getting an error because it's a valid operation, but I'm wondering what its purpose is. Are you getting paid by line count?

Comment: Either way, without seeing your inputs and calling code, it's really difficult to say anything.

Comment: with np.insert I can't change datatype. But I am wondering How to get last colum as 0 and 1 rather than 0.000 and 1.000. At the end I have to store last column in a separate file

Comment: My inputs are same that I have showed in the print result excluding last two columns

Comment: Also, don't use backticks if you indent your code. It's one or the other, not both

Comment: You have three input arguments. Please edit your question to contain a minimal example that I can copy into my shell and run to obtain the problematic result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179507/discussion-between-user10163680-and-mad-physicist).

Comment: `data_all` contains floats.  Any values you added to it (via insert) will also be floats.  This what the uniform `dtype` of numpy arrays means.  And since the original numbers are best displayed with scientific notation, the 1s and 0s will too (1.0000e+00).  If you don't want that dtype for the new columns, not add them to this array.  Make separate one with an integer dtype.

Answer (score 1):

you can convert your data type to object like this :

```
def set_label(data_all, Labels, hc):
    loc_1=len(data_all[0])
    labels= Labels
    insert_h = np.insert(data_all,loc_1,labels,axis=1)

    label_store =[]
    for i in range(len(labels)):
        hmax = labels[i]
        if hmax < hc:
            label_store.append(0)
        elif hmax > hc:
            label_store.append(1)
    loc_2= len(insert_h[0])
    #this is what I added to your code 
    insert_h = np.insert(np.array(insert_h,dtype='O'),loc_2,np.array(labels,dtype = np.int),axis=1)
    return insert_h
```

and your output would be like this :

```
array([[0.111886399, 2.83619339, 3.14394233, 1.0, 1],
       [0.229317271, 1.87929947, 3.14713896, 1.0, 1],
       [0.0369530173, 3.525601, 5.05051823, 1.5, 1],
       [0.156559513, 2.10847705, 3.8871538, 1.5, 1],
       [0.00244876157, 6.02824866, 10.2350953, 5.0, 5],
       [0.00938766706, 4.8969895, 6.28692713, 5.0, 5]], dtype=object)
```

or when you want to select your label and convert it to one hot convert labels type to integer :

```
np.array('your selected array',dtype = np.int)
```